# Does Amazon SNS support publishing SMSes in batch to different mobile numbers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns, phone-number

I understand that Amazon SNS supports [publishing messages in batch to SNS topics](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/publishing-messages-in-batch-to-amazon-sns-topics/). I wonder that the same thing can be done for publishing SMSes to mobile numbers?

My use case is to send out unique SMS for each mobile number while several numbers are processed with Spring Batch.

I have tried to use [PublishBatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_PublishBatch.html) API and unfortunately **phoneNumber** cannot be found as a request parameter of [PublishBatchRequestEntry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_PublishBatchRequestEntry.html).

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: What did you end up doing? Is Pinpoint any better when it comes to service limits and throughput

Answer (score 0):

SNS does not currently support `PublishBatch` calls when sending SMS (or push notifications). You will have to send each SMS as a separate `Publish` call until support is added.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean Pinpoint is better for sending batch messages